# Javascript - Hide a string from source code view

Tags: javascript, passwords

I have an excel file that has a password to protect it from editing. I have this line of code on a javascript page that opens the excel file for editing (the file opened by the function containing that line and edited by the function, not by the user):

```
var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Open(file,null,false,null,null,"Password");
```

the problem is that if a user will view the source code he can learn the password. The only protection I have for this issue, is including an external JS page that includes this function:

```
function ExcelPassword(){
    return "Password";
}
```

and change the line of code to:

```
var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Open(file,null,false,null,null,ExcelPassword());
```

This is an OK solution for me, but I wanted to know if there's a better way to hide the password from view. perhaps with some sort of a simple encription or even block the external JS file from view/download.

```
p.s.
I cannot use anything external (AJAX, JQuery) and there's no server involved.
```

Comment: No there is not. If the password is used in client's browser it can be viewed no matter what you do. Even encryption does not help..

Comment: What is your main goal with this? First protect excel then providing the password in js??

Comment: As @Hardy pointed out, if you open the Excel file on the client side, the password needs to be present on the client side, either in plain text or in encrypted form. If you only seek to exclude the password from the source, you can always issue an AJAX request to the server which returns the password. This way your client-side code will not contain the password, but it can still be captured super-easily e.g. using Firebug or any packet capture solution. Alternatively, you can remove the password protection server-side and serve the unprotected Excel file.

Comment: There's no server involved, And I cannot use anything other than javascript. The goal is to allow multiple users to access the excel file's data. The JS page makes sure that the information is edited in the correct format and that the file remains available for editing all the time. allowing users to edit the file localy can create problems in both issues (and some others I didn't mention). the only thing that keeps them from editing that file localy is that password.

Answer (score 0):

Well once a page is loaded at the client machine/browser. You can not protect the password form the client.

The best possible solution for your case could be that you make a server call through AJAX and  open the file for the client to edit. 
For this you can have a servlet or a php page to listen to the request and provide the password. Now send a flag  to the client that states that the client is authorized to edit the excel file.

The other solution can be to decrypt the password and then send it to the user. However this is not the best solution since, if the user gets to know your decryption mechanism, then your password can be easily decrypted by him

Comment: I'm added more information. The line of code I mentioned opens the file to be edited by a js function and not by the user. I'm working in a private WAN, so I cannot implement AJAX or JQuery or anything external.

Comment: Your first option is not a viable solution because anyone can look at the network logs on developer tools and view the request/response data as easily as viewing the JS source code.

Comment: @Lansana there is no secure way to hide any info on client side. The best you can do is, make it difficult for the user to extract it